# php not displaying in browser but it displays perfectly in dreamweaver 6

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I have 2 includes files header.php and footer.php and I fail to load them togheter to merge all togheter in one output. I can't manage to display them correctly after i watched a bunch of tutorials ain read multiple post i cant understand where I might fail in the attempt. I have to mention that I am new at this and someone please help me.

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Despre Noi</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"  type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="header">


            <div class="social">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/rss_3.gif" alt="social" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/rss_2.gif" alt="rss" width=                          "16" height="16" border="0" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/rss_1.gif" alt="rss" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a> Urmaritine pe canele Sociale 
        </div><!---end of social-->

        <div class="clr"></div><!--end of clr-->
        <div class="logo"> 
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="313" height="115" border="0" alt="logo" class="one"/></a>

                </div><!--end of logo-->
        <div class="menu">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active"><span>Acasa </span></a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html"><span>Servicii</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html"><span>Cocktail</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html"><span> Despre Noi </span></a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html"><span> Contact </span></a></li>
        </ul>

        </div><!--end of menu-->
        <div class="clr"></div><!--end of clr-->

    </div><!--end of header-->
</div><!--end of main_header-->
```

about.php

```
<pre><code>
    <?php
    include('root/includes/header.php');
    ?>



    <div class="body_container">
                        <div class="body">
                         <div class="body_bg">
                         <h2>Despre Noi</h2>
                            <
                            <p>   aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>

                            <p> aaaaasdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
                            <div class="clr"> </div>
                            </div><!--end of body_bg-->

                             <div class="left">
            <h2>Who we are<br />
              <a href="#" class="about">We bring value innovation and growth to your business</a></h2>
            <p>Nullam aliquam porttitor risus vel porta. Quisque porttitor posuere diam. Aenean vel dapibus leo. Quisque non neque dolor, vel imperdiet massa. Quisque a enim ac nisl tincidunt pharetra id ut nulla.<br />
              In vitae metus at neque elementum condimentum. Quisque fringilla porta metus, in posuere tellus ullamcorper in. Sed at metus velit. Aliquam consequat venenatis tortor, vel elementum mi laoreet tristique. </p>
            <h2>Our Mission</h2>
            <p>Sed tincidunt turpis posuere neque dictum quis faucibus felis tempus. Ut faucibus sem a nisi feugiat volutpat. Vivamus quis vulputate mauris. In suscipit sollicitudin mattis. Integer non nisl eu metus dapibus dapibus. Maecenas dui urna, luctus ac posuere at, semper vel lectus. Etiam lobortis porttitor tellus, ac adipiscing leo scelerisque ac. Aliquam iaculis orci sit amet est consequat tempus. Pellentesque quis dui ut purus auctor egestas. Ut ligula neque, aliquam elementum bibendum vitae, suscipit dictum lacus. <br />
              Proin lobortis consectetur eros vel mattis. Nullam aliquam porttitor risus vel porta. Quisque porttitor posuere diam. Aenean vel dapibus leo. Quisque non neque dolor, vel imperdiet massa. Quisque a enim ac nisl tincidunt pharetra id ut nulla.</p>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <h2>News and Events</h2>
            <p><a href="#" class="about">12 Dec 2015 | 0 comments</a><br />
              <strong>Duis nec porttitor lorem</strong><br />
              Integer lacus ante then ante ullamcorper ut vulputate..</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="about">18 Dec 2015 | 5 comments</a><br />
              <strong>Aenean interdum</strong><br />
              Vestibulum ante ipsum luctus ultrices antene posuere.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="about">4 Jan 2015 | 2 comments</a><br />
              <strong>Integer vitae nisl</strong><br />
              Duis volutpat ligula laoreet orci lectus placerat <br />
              Curabitur lectus malesuada pulvinar.</p>
            <div class="clr"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php include('includes/footer.php');
?>
</code></pre>
```

footer.php

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_container">
    <a href="/"><img src="images/footer_logo.gif" alt="logo_footer" width="145" height="59" border="0"/></a>
    <p class="right">© Copyright First Class Cocktail.
     <a href="#">Home</a> | 
     <a href="#">Servicii</a> | 
     <a href="#">Cocktail</a> | 
     <a href="#">Despre Noi</a> | 
     <a href="#">Contact</a><br/>
     <div class="clr"> </div>

    </div><!--end of footer container-->
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div><!--end of footer-->


</div><!--end of container-->
</body>
</html>
```

please help me and I apologize in advance if it is a simple solution!!  And thank you

Comment: never rely on the display of dreamweaver.

Comment: How are you loading the page into the browser? If you View > Source in the browser, do you see only generated HTML or does the PHP source code show up?

Comment: i am loading it from localhost . I a have a local server on my machine ..wamp.

Comment: when i click to see the source i see only the content, the file from includes are missing

Comment: Get firefox and firebug. Start debugging your code.

Comment: i dont know what you mean, i started firebug and the is simply not there( the one from includes) i think that i might be misstaking how i included the files in the first place, maybe the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `<pre><code>` in your actual document? If so you need to remove that because it will not process any code underneath it properly, so your includes will not work.

If that is fixed, assuming that 'root/includes/.php' is the actual location of your header/footer from the location of the about.php file, this should load. Again, make sure the path is correct FROM the directory of your about.php file (this would mean in the folder that the about.php file is located there is a directory called root).

Comment: i tried <?php
include('includes/header.php');
?> for the both. the files are included in the sitename/includes directories. if i use the statement of code above it doesn't work, thought in desing view form dreamweaver it works perfectly

Comment: And the about.php file is located in the root directory?

Comment: thank you!!! i dont know what happpedn nor can't explain it but it worked perfectly after restart...... Thank you again and sorry to waiste your time!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra End Container `</div>` in your header.php file. In fact if you want to end your container in footer.php file, remove `</div>` from your header.php, otherwise, remove it from footer.php.
Also your footer should be in `root/includes/footer.php`